# Migrate Wordpress Blog Data from Very old version to new

Tags: php, wordpress, data-migration

I have one blogging website created in wordress old version, *(Where for every users blog and post wordpress use to create new database and table)*, but in latest wordpress, I found for all users information is stored in single database.

I have recreated my website with latest wordpress version. **Now just wanted to migrate data *(Inclused users and users posts)* from existing website OLD to the NEW website.**

Any help and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How old is very old? Can you find out which version introduced the new database structure? Presumably if you upgrade to that version, it'll include a way of migrating existing data for you

Comment: mention the version of old wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way with least trouble would be to get all main releases between the old version and a current version. Then install them in a local system and upgrade the version plus data one version at a time.

Sounds tedious though.

Comment: That would be my suggestion, too. But it might be possible to skip some releases, depending on what changes those releases made. Of course, figuring that out is likely to take longer than running the upgrades.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks very much for suggestion. But for some reason I had to create new website with latest version instead of updating it. because in old version previous developer had done many changes in wordpress core to achieve his requirement instead of creating hooks. So i am looking to migrate data from old to new.

Comment: There is no-one hindering you from dumping the data from the upgraded version and import that into a "clean" current version of wordpress.